# Закрытие соединения с MySQL  в PDO

Tags: php, mysql

Собственно заинтересовала эта библиотека. Понравилось то, что более интересно оформлена работа с подготовленными выражениями. Но столкнулся с вопросом, который не понимаю. В MySQL чтобы закрыть соединение, нужно вызвать `close` собственно PDO, я не нашел такого. Более того, рекомендуют по завершению работы сделать `$Db = null;`. Ну судя по всему, будет вызван деструктор, но хотелось бы уточнить, оно точно закрывает сокет соединения с сервером базы данных или я что-то пропустил?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

судя по [документации](http://ua.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) именно так.

Upon successful connection to the database, an instance of the PDO class is returned to your script. **The connection remains active for the lifetime of that PDO object**. **To close the connection, you need to destroy the object** by ensuring that all remaining references to it are deleted--you do this by assigning NULL to the variable that holds the object. If you don't do this explicitly, PHP will automatically close the connection when your script ends.

Если вкратце - то что бы закрыть коннекшн нужно уничтожить объект